# How to get a Google Place ID from a Google GMS Address

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have seen previous posts regarding the conversion from a Google Place ID to an address; however I am interested in the opposite.

I have the GMS Address of the desired location but I want to acquire the Google Place ID in order to present more details to the user. From what I have seen on Google's iOS API website, you can attain a Google Place ID from an Autocomplete feature (for user searching), a selected location feature, or a current location feature.

My application intends to display multiple locations in which I already have the addresses for. The user can select individual locations for more details in addition to receiving details upon arrival. Therefore the features listed above are not ideal.

I have also tried using Google's Web API with features such as "Text Search Requests" & "Nearby Search Requests" however I am receiving "Zero Results".

Are there other methods that I haven't thought of and/or seen?

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Place ID finder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) in the Google Maps JavaScript API.

A [place ID](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id#id-overview) is a textual identifier that uniquely identifies a place. It is also  available for most locations, including businesses, landmarks, parks, and intersections. These IDs are stable, meaning that once you've identified the place ID for a place, you can reuse that value when you next look up that place.

You can use the same place ID across the Google Places API and a number of Google Maps APIs. For example, you can use the same place ID to reference a place in the **Places API**, the **Google Maps JavaScript API**, the **Google Maps Geocoding API**, the **Google Maps Embed API** and the **Google Maps Roads API**.

Here is the sample code use for this.

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13
        });

        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map
        });
        marker.addListener('click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
          infowindow.close();
          var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
          }

          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);
          }

          // Set the position of the marker using the place ID and location.
          marker.setPlace({
            placeId: place.place_id,
            location: place.geometry.location
          });
          marker.setVisible(true);

          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
              'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
              place.formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
      }
```

> Just take note that this example requires the Places library. Include
>   the libraries=places parameter when you first load the API. For
>   example:
>
> `script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"`